# Trying to make the image source one of the object's parameters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working in an hmtl.erb file trying to make the image source the link that is saved as a parameter for the product object.

```
<% @products.each do |categories,products| %>
<% products.each do |product| %>
<div class="container">    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <%= link_to product.name, product_path(product.permalink) %></div>
                <%-# the image source link below is not working -%>
                <div class="panel-body"><img src= product.default_image.path class="img-responsive" style="height: 250 width:250" alt="Image"></div>
                <div class="panel-footer"><%= product.short_description %></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><br>
<%end%>
```

I have tried putting that in quotes and doing @product.default_image.path. Nothing that I have tried works

Answer (score 0):

Use the rails helper [`image_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <%= image_tag(product.default_image.path, class: 'img-responsive') %>
</div>
```

Comment: That gives an undefined method error. "undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Well, then your `default_image` is `nil`, that's another problem.